# Node Js - Upgrade version, migration guide

Tags: node.js, npm, migration, upgrade, npm-install

I have Node version **v6.10.0** with Node Express 4.14.1.  I want to upgrade Node version to 7.6 or 8 to make use of `async await` features.

However, I'm not sure if it is as simple as update node with the command line or if there is something I should be aware of before migrating.

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

I have not found any migration guide on the site, github or whatsoever Internet.

Is it as simple as that as running a terminal instruction and done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Using nvm,using nvm,We can easily switch between different versions of node js.

- To Download nvm

  `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash`
- Install a Particular Version Of Node

  `nvm install version`
- Use a Node Version

  `nvm use version`

Comment: and if your are in a microservices architecture with many projects depending on different nodejs version you can put a file inside every projects which will be named `.nvmrc` and will contain the node js version of your project. By using the command inside one of your projects directory `nvm use`